# Spring repackage is adding a duplicate copy of all spring jars in BOOT-INF/classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I recently upgraded my project to `spring-boot` version 2.7.0. After this upgrade, when I run the jar of my maven profile, it gives me an `invocationTargetException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

I noticed that my built jar now contained a duplicate copy of all `org/springframework/boot/loader/` libraries inside the `BOOT-INF/classes` directory. This is what I see when I look inside the jar file by running `jar tvf jarfile`:

```
0 Wed Jun 29 20:06:28 PDT 2022 META-INF/
   492 Wed Jun 29 20:06:28 PDT 2022 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/
  5871 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/ClassPathIndexFile.class
  7675 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
  2551 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
  1483 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$DefinePackageCallType.class
  1535 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
 11154 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
  5932 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class

...

     0 Wed Jun 29 20:06:28 PDT 2022 BOOT-INF/
     0 Wed Jun 29 20:06:28 PDT 2022 BOOT-INF/classes/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/
  5871 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/ClassPathIndexFile.class
  7675 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
  2551 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
  1483 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$DefinePackageCallType.class
  1535 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
 11154 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
  5932 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 PST 1980 BOOT-INF/classes/org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class
```

In my `pom.xml`, I have a repackage step for a particular profile:

```
<profile>
            <id>profileName</id>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <configuration>
                       <classifier>someName</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
</profile>
```

This profile gives me the corrupted jar. Before the spring upgrade, it was working even with the repackage step so something must have changed. How can I avoid the duplicate spring boot libraries in my jar?

Comment: You are using profiles, do you by any change have the maven jar plugin configured as well? Or another `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the regular build section? In short it appears that there is too little information here, please add your full build file. And try with Spring Boot 2.7.1 (which was released a while ago).

Answer (score 0):

Please generate the Maven effective POM and search for repackage, you can find two executions with repackage goal but different execution id, which means repackage will be executed twice thus those spring boot classes will be packaged 2 times. During the second execution, it will treat those spring boot classes added by the first run as normal application classes and adds them into BOOT-INF/classes.

This shouldn't happen if you use spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.1.0 or later, the repackage id was pre-defined since version 2.1.0. The goal will be run only once because you refer the same id in your POM. Before version 2.1.0, there's a repackage goal pre-configured but no repackage id configured, therefore 2 repackage goals will be run in 2 executions.

Considering that you're using 2.7.0, likely some dependency in your POM introduced the extra repackage goal but with a different execution id.

You can refer Spring Boot Maven plugin document https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging